# Docker set container env variables from mounted drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  service:
    container_name: PDP-${ACTIVE_PROFILE}-API
    image: imge-name/api:v${TAG}
  build:
    context: .
  ports:
    - "${PORT}:8282"
  volumes:
  - /mnt/data/env_file:/application/env_file
  environment:
    JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -Dspring.profiles.active=${ACTIVE_PROFILE}
    POM_VERSION_DOCKER: ${POM_VERSION}
```

These variables are exported using jenkins and it works nicely

This is Dockerfile

```
.....
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

this is docker-entrypoint.sh

```
source ./env_file   - THIS IS PROBLEM env_file is unavailable
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar ./target/api-${POM_VERSION}.jar  - This is problem also JAVA_OPTS is unavailable as well as POM_VERSION
```

Comment: What's the actual question here :)?

Comment: updated to clarify :)